# Is it safer to declare in SQL Server stored procedure or I can use it like this?

Tags: sql-server

This is one of my stored procedures and I've got the following question:

Is this a safer way to declare `@LoginTime` for example or I can directly use `LoginTime` since it's in the same table INFO? Both way works but I want to know what's better and safer?

```
    @AccID varchar(21)
AS 
   DECLARE @id char(21)
   SELECT TOP 1 @id = CharNum FROM USERONLINE WHERE AccID = @accid

   DECLARE @LoginTime bigint
   SELECT @LoginTime = LoginTime FROM INFO WHERE UserId = @id

   DECLARE @Time bigint
   SELECT @Time = Time FROM INFO WHERE UserId = @id

   BEGIN TRAN
        UPDATE INFO 
        SET Time = @Time + (DATEDIFF(s,'19700101', GETDATE()) - @LoginTime)  
        WHERE UserId = @id

  COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: In it's current form your script is invalid - you may wish to update it.

Comment: Have you tried running your posted code? The first line: `@AccID varchar(21) AS` is invalid. It looks like you missed out the CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE FUNCTION part at the start. Run your code, make it valid and repost it.

Comment: It is valid. I just didn't included the rest of it since I thought it will be obvious that It's running. Sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        UPDATE iFO
            SET
                iFO.Time = iFO.Time + (DATEDIFF(s,'19700101', GETDATE()) - iFO.LoginTime)
        FROM INFO iFO
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 CharNum
                FROM USERONLINE
                WHERE
                    AccID = @AccID
            )uOL ON uOL.CharNum = iFO.UserId
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: Is this actually a better way in terms of security than mine? Also, it says an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'iFO' and 'uOL'

Comment: can you please provide your table structure with some data?

Comment: I understood. It's okay and I did it in this way: `UPDATE INFO 
        SET Time = (select Time + (DATEDIFF(s,'19700101', GETDATE()) - LoginTime)
                     from info 
                     where UserId = @id)
        WHERE UserId = @id` However is this better than my other one which I provided in the main post in terms of security mostly?

Comment: The reason you should do this in all one go is it stops the edge case of data changing in tables between you selecting and you updating it. This kind of edge case is pretty rare but very perplexing when it happens. Write simpler code with less bugs where possible. There is no security difference between the two pieces of code, unless you have a particular security concern that you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Time and LoginTime directly in the update. and it'll be only one atomic operation, with your queries outside the transaction those values could change before you update.

I missed the @id part, you can also get the id with a subquery inside update (or with a join as in Gaurav's answer)

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET ...
WHERE UserId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM ...)
```

Comment: So its safe to use them inside without declaring them first?

Comment: if your concern is security there is no difference afaik, taking into account that if you have separate queries they should be part of a transaction for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do in this way-

```
DECLARE @id char(21)
   SELECT TOP 1 @id = CharNum FROM USERONLINE WHERE AccID = @accid

BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE INFO
    SET Time =  (Time + (DATEDIFF(s,'19700101', GETDATE())) - LoginTime)
    FROM INFO 
    WHERE UserId = @id

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Is this actually a better way in terms of security than mine?

Comment: yes I think so. See you are not getting values exclusively from the table and then using it for update. the process which you are following is just making your sp little slow. The process which I am using here is just one atomic process.

Comment: Actually I do get values from the table: `Time, LoginTime ..` or you mean something else which I failed to understand =)? Also, why I should do select when I can directly update .. `TotalTime = TotalTime + ...`?

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying to tell you. Here I am doing all these in one atomic operation. You are first getting the values from the table in different operation and then using the same value  while updating but that is different operation.

Comment: Just dont get it why its better to use two different operations selecting from same table ? As to make sure, you say it should be better,faster and safer than mine provided ? Let me know so I can accept the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, I think so. If you want to verify, better you check the execution plans.

Comment: oh I get it. you mean it should be better since its selecting already values from table and its not directly inserting, correct?

Comment: BEGIN TRAN

        UPDATE INFO
        SET Time =  (Time + (DATEDIFF(s,'19700101', GETDATE()) - LoginTime)
        FROM INFO 
        WHERE UserId = @id

COMMIT TRAN can you try this query once? and check it's working or not?

Comment: It is working... so what's the best in that case? thanks for your time to answer to my questions.

Comment: this is the best solution for this problem. In my prior solution yes I was doing operation in single atomic operation but I was still querying table for getting values. This is the best possible solution which I know of. I am updating my solution above. could you please accept it as solution?

Comment: This solution doesn't reference the `USERONLINE` table at all which implies  it doesn't do what is required.

Comment: So can I use this as you suggested the last one but declare my `@id` with `USERONLINE` to do whats required?

Comment: I didn't really catch that statement. I suggest you take a look at @Gaurav answer and work out the difference and decide which one you want.

Comment: @Gaurav's suggestion didn't worked as you can see I posted a comment under his post with the error message. Would love if you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: check my solution now.

Comment: I added additional `)` after the `GETDATE()` since I believe it was missing and producing errors, is it on purpose missing or a typo? Also, as you suggested this should be a better approach for doing this update query than mines in the main post? let me know so we can accept the answer and finish it. thanks!

Comment: sorry, that was typo, just corrected it. And yes it's best approach because we are doing everything in one query(in one atomic process). I mean to say we are not selecting values and then updating table value.